Текст выделяется прямоугольным блоком
Не знаю как это убрать (использую Mac), первый раз сталкиваюсь.
Выделяется текст только какой-то ограничительной линии


Этот вопрос похож на: Проблемы при выделении кода в PyCharm. Если вы уверены что это не так, нажмите [edit], дайте ясно понять, чем ваш вопрос отличается от дубликата и/или почему ответы на него не помогают решить вашу проблему.

Это не кнопка инсерт, уже проверяла

тут смотрели? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50569424/13754729

судя по скрину, вы выделяете текст с зажатым колёсиком мыши. Это позволяет редактировать сразу несколько строк

В pycharm это называется Column selection mode, у меня доступно через Menu->Edit. Горячая клавиша Alt+Shift+Insert (у меня работает только с правыми Alt+Shift).

Спасибо большое!

Я нашла решение! Это Column Selection Mode (комбинация Cmd+Shift+8 на Mac)
